# How can I read a PDF file that is saved in the media folder in Django? I want to display it on an HTML page according to each id

Tags: python, django, pdf, django-models, django-views

I have developed a function within the views.py file.  I made a for loop on that html page, but only this PDF file is the issue. The name, ID number, and other details all function flawlessly.

```
{% for i in prid %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{i.id}}</td>
          <td>{{i.help_name}}</td>
          <td>{{i.help_service}}</td>
          <td>{{i.help_budget}}</td>
          <td><a href="/pdfview/" target="_blank"  type="application/pdf" height="50px" width="20px">view file</a></td>
          <td>{{i.help_message}}</td>
          <td style="font-weight: bold;">{{i.help_status}}</td>
          <td id="click" ><a href="/adminprojectsurvey/?surveyid={{i.id}}"> click to survey</a></td>
        </tr>
        
        {% endfor %}




#in views.py

def admin_project(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        add = helpingtable.objects.all()
        return render(request,'admin/project.html',{'prid':add})
    else:
        return render(request,'admin/index.html')
```

these are my code,

Comment: It's not able to find the PDF path properly, you can give proper path by using "url" atrribute of `FileField `, something like this `href="{{ i.your_pdf_file_field_name.url }}"`.
Make sure to replace `your_pdf_file_field_name` with the actual field name in your model that holds the path or URL to the PDF file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function I use. in my case I save the pdfs with my data rows id in their name, to be able to find them

```
def My_Open_PDF_PK(request,pk):

   my_dir = settings.MEDIA_ROOT

   mypkdone= Pktestata.objects.get(id=pk)

   file_name_pdf =  my_dir + "/" + str(mypkdone.id) + " " + "Packing_List.pdf"
   File_Save_Name =  str(mypkdone.id) + " " + "Packing_List.pdf"  

   with open(file_name_pdf, 'rb') as pdf:
    
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), 
        content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=' +""+ File_Save_Name
        return response
```

I hope it can be of help to you

Comment: can you define it, i don't understand clearly

Comment: in my dir I saved my pdf files with the mypkdone id at the beginning of the name + the string "Packing_List.pdf". With Open with I open the file I'm looking for. In the response I open the dialogue with the browser, to open the file I was looking for. I hope I've made myself clear

Comment: @SOURAV P
I want to add you. In Django I was unable to create a pdf and read it in the same view. With one view I create it, with a second view I search for it and open it.